How can I get Fluent UI panel to close?
I have 3 Blazor Components : 1 that has just a button for the markup but it opens up a Microsoft FLuent UI dialogue which takes a component (ChecklistItemDialogue) as a parameter, inside if checklistItemDialogue there are 2 components (ChecklistItemPanel and Newchecklistitem). All I am trying to do is simply close the model once the SubmitItems method is invoked inside of ChecklistItempanel. i want the model to close when this fires off. In addition , i would like to find a way to access the selectedItemTemplates and pass them up a couple of layers to update the UI once the request is successful
I havent been able to find a solution to do this correctly based on the documentation on the FLuent Ui Blazor website here is the code to the components :
OpenChecklistItemPanel :
@using SFSCheckList.Data.Repos
@using SFSCheckList.Data.Models


<FluentButton @onclick="() => LogDetails(Checklist)" Appearance="Appearance.Accent">
   Add checklist item 
</FluentButton>


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback SubmitItems { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Checklist? Checklist { get; set; }

    [Inject] private IDialogService DialogService { get; set; }

    private IDialogReference _dialog;

    public string width { get; set; } = "*";
    private async void LogDetails(Checklist checklist)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Details on the panel button !!!!");
        Console.WriteLine($"Checklist ID: {checklist.PK_ChecklistID}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Checklist Name: {checklist.ChecklistName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Checklist Description: {checklist.ChecklistDescription}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Start Date: {checklist.AvailableStartDate}");
        Console.WriteLine($"End Date: {checklist.AvailableEndDate}");
        Console.WriteLine($"FY: {checklist.FY}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Created: {checklist.LCTS}");
        await OpenPanelAsync();
    }

    private async Task OpenPanelAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Checklist.PK_ChecklistID.ToString());
        _dialog = await DialogService.ShowPanelAsync < ChecklistItemDialogue> (Checklist.PK_ChecklistID.ToString(),
            new DialogParameters<string>
                {
                    Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right,
                    Title = "Simple Form",
                    ShowDismiss = true,
                    Width = width,

                });

        DialogResult result = await _dialog.Result;
        HandlePanel(result);
    }



    private async Task HandlePanel(DialogResult result)
    {
        if (result.Cancelled)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Panel cancelled" );

        }
        else
        {
            var selectedTemplates = result.Data as List<ChecklistItemTemplate>;
            if (selectedTemplates != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Items submitted:");
                foreach (var template in selectedTemplates)
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine($"- {template.ItemName}: {template.ItemDesc} the itemsmsss"));
                }

                // Handle the selected templates as needed
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandleWidthChanged(string newWidth)
    {
        width = newWidth;
        Console.WriteLine("clicked onnnnn");
    }

    public EventCallback OnItemAdded { get; set; }
}

ChecklistItemDialogue :
@implements IDialogContentComponent<string>

<div>
    <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal">
        <ChecklistItemPanel ChecklistId="@Content" />
        @if (isPanelOpen)
        {
            <NewCheckListItem ChecklistId="@Content"/>

        }
    </FluentStack>
    <FluentButton OnClick="@(() => isPanelOpen = !isPanelOpen)">Open new panel </FluentButton>

</div>

@code {



    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback SubmitItemTemplate { get; set; }


    [Parameter]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    private bool isPanelOpen = false;
    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        // Logging to verify the content
        Console.WriteLine($"Content: {Content}");
    }

}


ChecklistItemPanel :
 @using SFSCheckList.Data.Repos
@using SFSCheckList.Data.Models 


<FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Vertical">
    <h3>Add Checklist Item</h3>
    <SelectecChecklistItemTemplates SelectedItemTemplates="SelectedItemTemplates" />
@foreach (var template in ChecklistItemTemplates)
{
    <FluentCard Width="20rem" >
        <FluentLabel>@template.ItemName</FluentLabel>
        <FluentLabel>@template.ItemDesc</FluentLabel>
        <FluentButton @onclick="@(() => AddChecklistItem(template))">+</FluentButton>
    </FluentCard>
}
    <FluentDatePicker Value="startDate" ValueChanged="@(e => startDate = e.Value)" Placeholder="Select Start Date" />
    <FluentDatePicker Value="endDate" ValueChanged="@(e => endDate = e.Value)" Placeholder="Select End Date" />
    <FluentButton @onclick="SubmitItems">Submit</FluentButton>
</FluentStack>
@* <FluentButton @onclick="@OpenPanelAsync" Appearance="Appearance.Accent">
    Open panel (&gt;&gt;)
</FluentButton> *@

<style>
    .checklist-item {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        width: 20rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 5px;
        list-style-type: none;
        background-color: white;
    }

        .checklist-item:hover {
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }
</style>


@code {
   

    [Inject] private IDialogService DialogService { get; set; }

    private CheckListItemList itemList = null;


    public class ChecklistItemDialogParameters
    {
        public string ChecklistId { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public IDialogReference Dialog { get; set; }
    }

 

    [Parameter]
    public ChecklistItemDialogParameters Parameters { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string ChecklistId { get; set; }
    public List<SFSCheckList.Data.Models.ChecklistItemTemplate>? SelectedItemTemplates { get; set; } = null;
    [Parameter]
    public string Width { get; set; } = "20vw";

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<ChecklistItemTemplate> TemplateSelected { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    protected ChecklistRepo? checklistRepo { get; set; }

    private IDialogReference _dialog;

    public string width { get; set; } = "20vw";
    public string height { get; set; } = "100vh";
    private DateTime startDate { get; set; } = new DateTime(2024, 6, 1);
    private DateTime endDate { get; set; } = new DateTime(2024, 6, 30);

    List<SFSCheckList.Data.Models.ChecklistItemTemplate> ChecklistItemTemplates = new List<SFSCheckList.Data.Models.ChecklistItemTemplate>();

    private async Task getTemplates()
    {
        ChecklistItemTemplates = await checklistRepo.GetItemTemplates();
        foreach (var template in ChecklistItemTemplates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(template.ItemName);
        }
    }



    private async Task SubmitItems()
    {
        if (SelectedItemTemplates == null || !SelectedItemTemplates.Any())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No templates selected.");
            return;
        }

        foreach (var template in SelectedItemTemplates)
        {
            await checklistRepo.CreateItemFromTemplate(template, Guid.Parse(ChecklistId), startDate, endDate);
        }

    }


    private async Task AddChecklistItem(ChecklistItemTemplate template)
    {
        await TemplateSelected.InvokeAsync(template);
        SelectedItemTemplates.Add(template);
        Console.WriteLine("template" + template.ItemName);

    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        await getTemplates();
        SelectedItemTemplates = new List<SFSCheckList.Data.Models.ChecklistItemTemplate>(); // Initialize here

    }
  
}



To close a dialog from within the dialog you need to use the CascadingParameter FluentDialog it will have the methods required.

thanks for the insight biran could you should me an example of how this is implemented

Dialog content component :
@implements IDialogContentComponent<MenuState>
 ...
<FluentDialogFooter Style="width: 100%;">
    <FluentButton OnClick="@Close">Close</FluentButton>
...
</FluentDialogFooter>

@code { 
    [CascadingParameter]
    public FluentDialog Dialog { get; set; } = default!;

...
    private  async Task Close()
    {
        await Dialog.CancelAsync();
    }
}

In your case you would be calling the close within the method not on a click..

cool that makes sense, any idea how i can update/ refresh a parent component once that panel closes ?

https://www.fluentui-blazor.net/Dialog
Read the section "Exchange data between dialog and calling component" there is two ways.
